# Error -2 connecting to redis://redis:6379:6379. Name or service not known

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, redis

I was hoping to get some insight to what I am missing, currently trying to run a docker-compose config with python (walrus for db wrapper) and redis image, but I keep receiving the same error:

redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis://redis:6379. Name or service not known.

I tried different solutions on stack overflow to fix this but still nothing is working.

Here are the related docker-compose config:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

    redis:
      image: redis:latest
      container_name: redis
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      command: ["redis-server"]
      entrypoint: redis-server --appendonly yes

    consumers:
      build: ./consumers
      container_name: consumers
      environment:
        - REDIS_HOST=redis://redis
      command:  "./run.sh"
      depends_on:
        - redis
      restart: always
      tty: true


networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /consumers

# Copy Dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY run.sh .

# Install Dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
ENV REDIS_HOST=redis://redis
RUN chmod a+x run.sh

# Run executable consumer.py
CMD [ "./run.sh"]
```

And connection in python using walrus to redis:

```
rdb = Database(host=os.getenv("REDIS_HOST", "localhost"), port=6379)
```

Locally without docker the setup works fine. Any direction in this case would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Try creating a custom network & pass that explicitly in the containers definition instead of the default

Comment: Thank you, it does not seem to work :/. 
`redis:
      image: redis:latest
      container_name: redis
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      command: ["redis-server"]
      networks:
        - connections
      entrypoint: redis-server --appendonly yes
  
consumers:
      build: ./consumers
      container_name: consumers
      environment:
        - REDIS_HOST=redis://redis
      command:  "./run.sh"
      networks:
        - connections
      depends_on:
        - redis
      restart: always
      tty: true

  
networks:
  connections:
    name: connections`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration made it work, removed entrypoint, created a new custom network and exposed port. REDIS_HOST was modified to redis i.e. container name. All together made it work but while trying only one of these the problem persisted.

```
version: '3.5'

services:

    redis:
      image: redis:latest
      container_name: redis
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      expose: 
        - 6379:6379
      command: ["redis-server"]
      networks:
        - connections

    
    consumers-g1:
      build: ./consumers
      container_name: consumers-g1
      environment:
        - REDIS_HOST=redis
      command: "./run.sh"
      expose: 
        - 6379:6379
      networks:
        - connections
      restart: always
      tty: true


networks:
  connections:
    name: connections
    driver: bridge
```